# Create edit Popup link in Rally for User Stories

Tags: rally

I have created edit links before for TestCases and other items in Rally using the JavaScript API using:

```
var editTestCase = function(objectID) {
            rally.sdk.util.Navigation.popupEditPage("/testcase/" + objectID);
};
```

However when I try to do a similar thing for user stories, I can't create the link properly. I assume that this is because I don't know the item name to use (i.e. the string to replace testcase with. I have tried userStory and userstory and oid, and none of those work.

I am trying to call this function using the code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="editUserStory(' + objectID + ');"><img src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/images/icon_edit.gif"></a>
```

I have checked and my value for objectID is initialised and is a valid and correct object ID for a user story.

when I try to create a link in this way, the trunk of the URL shows

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/null/edit.sp?
```

Whereas when I follow an edit link from else where it reads as (I have removed query strings for clarity):

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/ar/edit.sp?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Webservices object model, User Stories are Hierarchical Requirements. Thus:

`rally.sdk.util.Navigation.popupEditPage("/hierarchicalrequirement/" + objectID);`

Should do the trick for you.